# Prove $\operatorname{stab}_G(g \cdot x) = g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose a group $G$ acts on a set $X$. The stabilizer in $G$ of $x \in X$ is
$$
\operatorname{stab}_G(x) = \{a \in G : a \cdot x = x \}
$$ For each $g \in G$, let 
$$
g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1} = \{gag^{-1} : a \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x)\}
$$ I have to prove that $$ \operatorname{stab}_G(g \cdot x) = g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1} $$
by showing that

- $\operatorname{stab}_G(g \cdot x) \subseteq g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$
- $g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1} \subseteq \operatorname{stab}_G(g \cdot x) $

Comment: Yes, so prove it! :-) And tell us where you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, I should've specified where I was having trouble. This is my first question on here, so I'll know for next time, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\in\operatorname{stab}_G(g\cdot x)$; then $a\cdot(g\cdot x)=g\cdot x$, that is
$$
(ag)\cdot x=g\cdot x
$$
or else
$$
(g^{-1}ag)\cdot x=x
$$
Therefore $b=g^{-1}ag\in\operatorname{stab}_G(x)$, which means that
$$
a=gbg^{-1}
$$
where $b\in\operatorname{stab}_G(x)$. This proves one of the inclusions; can you show the other one with a similar technique?

Comment: Both are great answers, the question just happened to click while looking at this one. Thanks for giving me hints instead of just the answer, it helps a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Note that $\operatorname{stab}_G(g\cdot x)\subseteq g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$ iff $g^{-1}\operatorname{stab}_G(g\cdot x)g\subseteq\operatorname{stab}_G(x)$. To prove the latter, suppose that $a\in\operatorname{stab}_G(x)$, and show that $(g^{-1}ag)\cdot x=x$.

To show that $g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}\subseteq\operatorname{stab}_G(g\cdot x)$, again let $a\in\operatorname{stab}_G(x)$, and see whether $gag^{-1}$ stabilizes $g\cdot x$. Both are straightforward calculations if you understand the defining properties of group actions.